# How to allow only Admin (or some user) to edit the pages in Django?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-admin

In Django webpage(page can view by all), need to allow only certain people to edit the webpage and other people can just view the webpage.

In Django-admin page's Users table,I've changed the certain users to "Can view" option and added certain users "Can edit" option. It is not working as per expected.

For reference: [image]

Getting this error,

```
POST "/admin/auth/user/4/change/ HTTP/1.1" 302
```

Actual result to be is

```
 POST "/admin/auth/user/4/change/ HTTP/1.1" 200
```

And that change result needs to be changed successfully and reflect

Comment: what do mean "added certain users "can edit" option"? you mean "can change"? You're not seeing an error, you're seeing a redirect (302), it would help if you tell us what you see in the browser (what page you're redirected to)

Comment: Yes, I mean "can change" and it is redirected to Users main page that is "http://localhost:8000/admin/auth/user/"

Comment: so a user with "can change" permission on the `User` model cannot open the /change/ page for a specific `User` but gets redirected to the user list instead?

Comment: No, now my problem is any user can view, change, add and delete the content in the webpage. But I want to restrict view access to few people and few people to change the content through "Can change" with change user-permission

Comment: that should just work, assuming you give the correct permissions. In your example above you're setting permissions for the `TaskManager` model, but in the urls you show urls for the `User` model. Those are not related.

Comment: Ah, I need to limit access in `Taskmanager` model

Comment: Which is what you did in your screenshot. Looks all fine. It should work for the user with id 4, this user can view `Taskmanager` instances but not change/add/delete.

Comment: Note that `POST` always returns a 302, that's normal. When you post something, the server must redirect. That's good practice, so that users don't re-post the same thing when refreshing their page.

Comment: Yes, Even after limiting that user with view permission, that user is still able to perform CRUD operations.

Comment: No Superuser is another user

Comment: are you saying a user that only has "can_view_taskmanager" permissions and isn't superuser is able to change and delete a "taskmanager" object inside the django admin? Or in one of your own views?

Comment: No in my view(in the webpage) and not in the django-admin page

Comment: About Permissions: "It’s used by the Django admin site, but you’re welcome to use it in your own code." You have to implement the logic yourself.

Comment: Django has decorators that help you with that, for example the [permission_required](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#the-permission-required-decorator) decorator

Comment: Thanks a lot @dirkgroten. That Decorators are really helping this issue to resolve

Answer (score 3):

**views.py**

```
from django.views.generic.edit import UpdateView
from myapp.models import Author

class AuthorUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Author
    fields = ['name']
    template_name_suffix = '_update_form'
```

**app/author_update_form.html**

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated and request.user.is_admin %}
<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Update">
</form>
{% else %}
<p>Display data</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: What are the fields you've in your `Aurthor` model.

Comment: @gomathisubramanian They can be anything you want. In your `views.py`, just list the fields you want listed in the template.